# Game Rotation Collision Problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, maze

Im attempting to make a basic maze game with a slight twist. At set intervals (set by a timer event) the maze rotates 90%. The problem I'm having is in regards to the hitTestPoint. The hit test works prior to the maze roataion and works after a full 360% rotation but stops working during the 90%, 180% and 270% rotation points. I have exhausted all my knowledge (As limited as a 5 month AS3 programmer) in AS3 to resolve this problem and am at my wits end.

The maze is in a container and the container is rotating, this is so that the maze in effect has a secondary moving pivot point that continually follows the player around tha maze. additionally the container is moving on key press not the player.

Could anyone please halp me by explaining what is causing the problem, how I can fix it and if possible show me an example of the code I should be using.

Here is what I have so far.

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;

var speed:Number = 5;

var northSpeed = speed;
var southSpeed = speed;
var eastSpeed = speed;
var westSpeed = speed;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var Orientation:int = 0;

var count:int = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
var time = 60;

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MovePlayer);
containBox.maze.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitWalls);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyDepressed);
containBox.maze.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);

timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandle);

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    txt_time.text = time;
    time--;
}

function hitWalls(event:Event):void
{
    if (upPressed==true && containBox.maze.hitTestPoint(player.x,player.y,true))
    {
        northSpeed = 0;
        player.y = player.y+=2;
    }
    else
    {
        northSpeed = speed;
    }
}


function spin(event:Event):void
{
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        txt_time.text = "TIMES UP!";
    }
    if (time <= 54)
    {
        containBox.rotation = 90;
        Orientation = 1;
    }
    if (time <= 50)
    {
        containBox.rotation = 180;
        Orientation = 2;
    }
        if (time <= 48)
    {
        containBox.rotation = 270;
        Orientation = 3;
    }
        if (time <= 46)
    {
        containBox.rotation = 0;
        Orientation = 0;
    }

}

function MovePlayer(event:Event):void
{
    if (Orientation == 0)
    {
        if (upPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y +=  northSpeed;
        }
        if (downPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y -=  southSpeed;
        }
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x +=  westSpeed;
        }
        if (rightPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x -=  eastSpeed;
        }
    }
    else if (Orientation == 1)
    {
        if (upPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x +=  5;
        }
        if (downPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x -=  5;
        }
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y -=  5;
        }
        if (rightPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y +=  5;
        }
    }
    else if (Orientation == 2)
    {
        if (upPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y -=  5;
        }
        if (downPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y +=  5;
        }
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x -=  5;
        }
        if (rightPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x +=  5;
        }
    }
    else if (Orientation == 3)
    {
        if (upPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y +=  5;
        }
        if (downPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.y -=  5;
        }
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x +=  5;
        }
        if (rightPressed)
        {
            containBox.maze.x -=  5;
        }
    }
}

function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            {
                upPressed = true;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            {
                downPressed = true;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            {
                leftPressed = true;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            {
                rightPressed = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}

function KeyDepressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            {
                upPressed = false;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            {
                downPressed = false;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            {
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
            };
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            {
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks, 
Reece.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2D coordinate system transformation to do a proper comparison. See, the player basically stands on a fixed point, thus `(player.x, player.y)` is fixed, and `hitTestPoint()` uses the coordinates supplied as local to the `this` object, in your case the maze. To get the player's coordinates in the maze's system, you need first get global position, then derive local position, there are functions for that, `localToGlobal()` and `globalToLocal()` respectively.

```
function hitWalls(event:Event):void
{
    var p:Point=new Point(player.x,player.y);
    var dp:Point=containBox.maze.globalToLocal(player.parent.localToGlobal(p));
    // now test vs dp instead of player.
    if (upPressed==true && containBox.maze.hitTestPoint(dp.x,dp.y,true))
    {
        northSpeed = 0;
        player.y = player.y+=2;
    }
    else
    {
        northSpeed = speed;
    }
}
```